# Cloning git keeps loading

Tags: visual-studio-code, gitlab, cloning

It's my first time trying to clone a git from GitLab into VSCode on my windows pc. The cloning process keeps loading for over 15 minutes on end every single time (I've tried multiple times). Any suggestions of what I could be doing wrong?

Click the clone button in GitLab, click on VSCode (html) and select a destination folder. It starts cloning and I would expect this to finish at some point...

Comment: Try cloning from the terminal/command line. There are so many things that could cause this. Bad network connection? Huge repository and slow network? Low disk space? Auth error tripping up your vscode plug-in? Bug in your git vscode plug-in? This isn’t a programming question - it’s either an issue with your computer or network connection or a bug/compatibility issue in whatever you’re using to clone. Good luck!

Comment: Did you examine the target folder? Is `.git` in there? Is it big?

Comment: I think it must have been an authentication issue, the command line worked, but only after changing my password for GitLab